# difference between using getAttributeNode and setAttributeNode

Tags: javascript, attributes, tags

I want to know the difference between using getAttributeNode and setAttributeNode:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG")[0];
x.getAttributeNode("src").value = "pic_bulbon.gif";
x.setAttributeNode("src").value = "pic_bulbon.gif";
```

Comment: It's in the name, one `set`s the attribute, the other `get`'s the attribute. They are not being used properly in your code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Element.getAttributeNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttributeNode) returns the specified attribute of the specified element, as an Attr node.

[`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute) is used for adding a new attribute or changes the value of an existing attribute on the specified element.

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG")[0]; // Get the first image element
console.log(x.getAttributeNode("src")); // Returns the src value of image
x.setAttributeNode("src", "pic_bulbon.gif"); // Set src value of image
```